# Text is not expanding td elements on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

I need some help in a sizing question. If you view the following code in desktop browsers, everything is sized as it should be. If you try to open it on a mobile phone (I have tested it with several iPhones), the td (white with grey border) is not resized properly. The td element is resized correct, if there is a span element that's causing the overflow.

```css
div.highlighter-rouge {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

div.highlight {
  width: 100%;
}

.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

pre.highlight {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

pre code {
  white-space: pre;
}

table {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  word-wrap: anywhere;
}

table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 13px;
}

table tr th :last-child,
table tr td :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

table tr th :first-child,
table tr td :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

td.rouge-code>pre>span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.highlight .nt {
  color: #000080;
}

.highlight .s1 {
  color: #d01040;
}

html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="language-bash highlighter-rouge">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre class="highlight"><code><table class="rouge-table"><tbody><tr><td class="rouge-gutter gl"><pre class="lineno">1
2</pre>
    </td>
    <td class="rouge-code">
      <pre>ausearch <span class="nt">-c</span> <span class="s1">'ajp-bio-0:0:0:0'</span> <span class="nt">--raw</span> | audit2allow <span class="nt">-M</span> my-ajpbio0000
semodule <span class="nt">-i</span> my-ajpbio0000.pp</pre>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried many things now, but my level of knowledge about this, just leads to trial and error. If you don't really like the solution with tables, I can also create a version with the exact same behaviour without them.

https://codepen.io/ribbonCaptain/pen/GRrqgpE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.rouge-table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.rouge-table td pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

...will do it. See it [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/jOyrbOB).

There's not [much](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) to explain.

Comment: I invested more time in this. Your answer is correct, as it circumvents the issue (breaking, instead of overflowing and resizing). I'm suspecting a bug here. Now this is an example of a minimized issue set-up: https://codepen.io/ribbonCaptain/pen/GRrqgpE. If you try to render it on a mobile phone i.e. iPhone the span without a space in front is resizing the parent correctly.

Comment: @accentWool, I'm not sure I understand what's the desired behavior here. Nowhere in your question are you defining what *"the element is resized correct"* or *"resized properly"* really means. What are you trying to achieve? Could you describe it unequivocally? In my estimation, what you're after can be solved using simpler markup and some CSS, but still, before I can be sure you have to describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry that I am not precise in my question. Maybe pictures can make clearer what my initial problem is. This is how it should look like (Android): https://sos-de-fra-1.exo.io/test883619462/6EE441F5-5A3C-42DD-A47C-8D417C2CD88C.jpeg and this is how it actually looks like (iPhone): https://sos-de-fra-1.exo.io/test883619462/89B99551-1D22-43E3-9DF4-CF09C08FF91B.png.
How can the first yellow box on iPhone browsers be resized that it contains the text like in the Android picture version?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what's the difference between `not-ok` and `ok` versions. I'm testing this in Chrome and both examples behave similarly on Android and iPhone. What browsers are you using on each?

Comment: Question: is [this](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/wvgWZBr) displaying properly on iPhone, from your pov?

Comment: To answer your question: This is not displayed correctly, if the span is overflowing. The text is outside the box at the end. I tested on iPhone 7&11 with newest OS, with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge and Brave. I also tested inside my wireless network and on mobile data. But just to be sure, you see what I mean when looking at the pictures I provided, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230513/discussion-between-accentwool-and-tao).